# How do I disable/enable mouse/tap events for a DOM node and all its descendant elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a DOM like this:

```html
<div id="root">
   <div>
     <button>Button</button>
   </div>
   <section>
     <a href="#">Link</a>
     <span onclick="alert(1);">Text</span>
   </section>
</div>
```

I want to make all the elements inside the `#root` node unable to be clicked/tapped. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS pointer events

```css
#root {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
   <div>
     <button>Button</button>
   </div>
   <section>
     <a href="#">Link</a>
     <span onclick="alert(1);">Text</span>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, sounds very interesting (to use CSS). Is this working only for modern browsers? How about mobile? Thanks!

Comment: It works in mobile browsers. You can see browser compatibility here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events @AwQiruiGuo

Comment: Thanks, this is a perfect way. Useful and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function at click of button 
Function atbottonclick(){$(this).css('pointer-events','none')}
But you need to prevent keyboard events also for totally disable them. So if you can disable these elements then go for it.